what is spiritual wealth or energy?
What is spiritual wealth or energy?
Here are three pointers:

In Aghora series, by Dr. Robert Sovoda.

Main protagonist Sri Aghori vimalananda tell about his guru taking spiritual wealth of a master(As punishment).


Famous sadhak in a podcast

Said about a ritual(Trantric) to transfer spiritual wealth from one sadhak to another.


During diksha:

Read few articles, where a real Guru gives some energy to aspirant. I am guessing its spiritual energy.



Now the question is, what is spiritual wealth?

Spiritual wealth is the accumulation of subtle, divine, and transformative energies or qualities, attained through spiritual practices, devotion, or initiation from a Guru. It is distinct from material wealth, as it enriches the soul and elevates consciousness, aiding in the realization of higher truths and liberation (moksha).

It’s combination of many things, like if we say healthy person (mental as well as physical).  Did anyone wrote some books / article on it ?

Hey, I noticed and approved this edit of yours. Thank you for taking the time to improve the site for other people. It's really helpful. I hope you stick around and keep asking interesting questions. Welcome to HSE.
